# How to add data to firebase at document field instead of collection field?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This code allow me to add user's email to collection field.

```
  addContact(member:member){
const promise = new Promise<string>((resolve) => {
  const db = firebase.firestore();
  const productsRef = db.collection('user/');
     // Add to Database
  productsRef.add({
    user: member.user
  }).then(docRef => {
    resolve(docRef.id);
  });
});
return promise;}
```

[image]

How to modify this code to make the user's email save in document field instead of collection field in the firebase?

Comment: What exactly do you want..!?

Answer (score 1):

You are saving saving the users email in a document field. The concept of collection field does not exist. Using the add method on the collection generates a document. However I would rewrite your code like this:

```
async function addContact(member: member) {
    const docRef = await firestore().collection('users').add({user: member.user})
    return docRef; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn`t get what do you want exactly, but if you want to add data to a specific doc, then you can use the doc() method and it has many features like update specific fields, or merge new data into the ones that already exists, or completely override the entire doc. There are methods to all os these features and some others that you can find in the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference). If you want to set some data into a doc you can make like this:

```
const productsRef = db.collection('user/');
return productRef.doc('{document id}').set(user)
.catch((err) => err);
```

If the id you pass as a parameter to doc() doesn`t exist, it will be created.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to write to a document, you must know the exact, complete path to that document.

So in this case you'll need to specify the collection name (which you do) *and* the document name (which you don't). You can either know the ID (since you've looked it up before), or you can determine it by [using a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries).

Once you know the entire path, you can build a reference to that document, and then update the document to add a field as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data